# Bitmap loading in listview is smooth, caching to SD however lags the app

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

Let me just start by saying I have a rather unusual source of images. I'm getting the bitmaps that need to be loaded from ID3 tags on an mp3 file.

Whenever I load the cover art and save it to the SD storage I get lagg. The odd thing is that all the loading and saving is happening on a background thread so it should not influence the UI thread. + I'm only running one operation at a time and it still laggs.

Once I have saved all the images to disk and I construct an array with all path names to the saved files it scrolls like butter and all images load without any delay. So the issue clearly is the caching to SD which is not happening on the UI thread. (I might be wrong about it though, so that is where you guys come in) The image loading from file is done using Universal Image Loader btw, but that is not causing any problems :)

Here is a snippet of my code that stores the cover art:

```
public ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

//this is where I schedule tasks for all mp3 files to be executed using the threadpool, 
//it is interrupted as soon as the user interacts with the listview (which should not be
//nessecary as it is not running any code on the UI thread)

public void preloadImages(){
    for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(scrolling){
            return;
        }
        if(items[i].type.equalsIgnoreCase("music") && imagePathArray[i] == null){
            ImageRunnable imgr = new ImageRunnable(items[i].pathname, null, i);
            executor.execute(imgr);
        }
        if(scrolling){
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

custom runnable

```
//the custom runnable used to call the getCover method on separate thread
private class ImageRunnable implements Runnable {
    private String url;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private boolean running = true;
    private int position;

    public ImageRunnable(String path, ImageView img, int pos) {
        url = path;
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(img);
        position = pos;
    }

    public void terminate() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        final String coverPath = getCover(url, position);
    }
}
```

The getcover method

```
private String getCover(String filepath, boolean refresh, int pos){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "BEGIN function");
    File file = new File(filepath);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "File read");
    MusicMetadataSet meta = null;

    try {
        meta = new MyID3().read(file);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "id3 read");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error reading id3 tag of file");
        return null;
    }
    if(meta != null) {
        try {
            MusicMetadata metasimple = (MusicMetadata) meta.getSimplified();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "simplified");
            int length = filepath.length();
            String albumname = filepath.substring(length-15, length-5).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]", "_");
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "album string");
            File fileo = new File(path, "id3tag/"+albumname+"_icon.jpg");
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "file created");
            File dir = new File(path, "id3tag/");
            if(!dir.isDirectory()){
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            if(!fileo.exists() || refresh){
                try {
                    fileo.createNewFile();
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(fileo);

                    Vector<ImageData> fileList = metasimple.getPictureList();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "got pic list");
                    ImageData data = fileList.lastElement();
                    if(fileList.size() == 0){
                        imagePathArray[pos] = "error";
                        return imagePathArray[pos];
                    }
                    byte[] rawimage = data.imageData;
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "got raw");
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawimage, 0, rawimage.length);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "decoded bmp");
                    bitmap = bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 64, 64, false);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "scaled bmp");
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "compr bmp");
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "recycled");

                    meta = null;
                    rawimage = null;
                    fileList = null;
                    options = null;
                    metasimple = null;
                    bitmap = null;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            imagePathArray[pos] = Uri.decode(fileo.toURI().toString().replace("file:/", "file:///"));
            return imagePathArray[pos];
        }catch (NoSuchElementException e){
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Ok I have found the issue, but no solution yet. Thanks everyone who helped so far! The bottleneck seems to be the read operation on the ID3 object. Why and how it is blocking the main thread I do not know but I'm going to try and minimize the usage of that object and see where it leads me :)

Comment: (I can't post as answer as I'm a new user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the issue, but no solution yet. Thanks everyone who helped so far! The bottleneck seems to be the read operation on the ID3 object. Why and how it is blocking the main thread I do not know but I'm going to try and minimize the usage of that object and see where it leads me :)

After doing this it only lags on the initial caching which happens only once for every file so no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently dealing with the same issue right now as well.

For me it appears to be multiple GC calls which pause all threads, including the UI thread in order to find resources to free up!

Check your LogCat messages to confirm, look for entries with the tag `dalvikm`

Comment: I'm getting absolutely no dalvikm errors in my logcat :/ So I don't think we have the same issue here.

Comment: Did you check under debug/verbose? They wouldn't come up as errors

Comment: Checked all of them, not a single dalvikm entry

Comment: Hmm your code definitely seems to indicate that is the issue, especially since you are calling bitmap.recycle() manually which would trigger a GC. If you are planning on supporting only Android 3.0 and above, remove that and see if there is any improvement

Comment: Ok I'll see what it does, but as far as I understood by reading the docs the recycle() function just tells the GC the bitmap is not needed anymore. Which is exactly why I was calling it.

Comment: And I forgot to mention it also lags when that if statement isn't true, so no bitmap is created nor recycled.

Comment: It was only really needed in versions of Android below 3.0 where bitmap data was stored in native memory instead of the dalvik heap so it needed to manually be freed up. The GC will handle it normally in 3.0 and above

Comment: I removed the recycle and there is no difference in log output, only thing I noticed is maybe even more lag when scrolling. I also cleared my cache dir so it has to save all files again. On a sample of 100 unique mp3 files I got exactly one dalvikm error:

    `dalvikvm﹕ JIT code cache reset in 0 ms (4096 bytes 2/0)`

Which was most likely caused by a different bit of code fired before this...

Answer (score 0):

Try to minimize allocation of new bitmaps. First you can make one bitmap 64x64 and draw in it instead of using creatScaledBitmap.

Second you can reuse bitmap for decoding by passing it to decodeByteArray through BitmapFactory.Options

Comment: Once again the bitmaps aren't the issue, I think I found a possible reason though. I/O operations seem to pause apps no matter where you run them so that might explain the lagg. Now on to look for a proper way to actually read/write files in android...